# ajax php sql populate dependent comboboxes

Tags: php, ajax

I'm just a beginner for all this php ajax things. I populate one of my combobox from database but I can't populate second one.

I need to populate Machine combobox according to Proses value.
And finally fill Envanter no with Id. 
Thanks for help!
Here is my code

My database table main

Process |  Machine |   ID
Bolzen  |    M1    |    1
Bolzen  |     M2   |    2
Bolzen  |     M3   |    3
Platte  |    M4    |    5
Platte  |    M4    |    7

Here is my code

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content"  style="background-color:#EEEEEE;position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:138px; top:101px; width:770px; height:450px">
 <form action="" name="myform" id="myform">
  <p><center> MFT1.2 SPC Girisleri Ölcüm Programi</center></p>
    <center><p> Tarih:&nbsp&nbsp <span id="mydate"> </span>
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <script type="text/javascript">
    date();
    </script>
    Machine No:
    <select name="Machine">
        <option value="000" selected = "selected"></option>


            </select>           
    </center></p>

    <center><p>
    Vardiya:&nbsp&nbsp
        <select name="Vardiya">
            <option value="000" selected="selected" >
            </option>
            <option>
              1. Vardiya
            </option>
            <option>
              2. Vardiya
            </option>
            <option>
              3. Vardiya
            </option>
        </select>   
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp            
    Envanter No:
    <input type="text" name="envanter" disabled="disabled"/>
    </center></p>
    <center><p>

    Proses:&nbsp&nbsp

            <?php
        // Load field datas into List box

            $cn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","12345678") or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
            $res=mysql_select_db("OlcumTakip",$cn) or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
            $res=mysql_query("select DISTINCT Proses from main;") or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
            ?>
        <select name="Proses">
            <option value="000" selected = "selected"></option> 
        <?php
        while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
        echo "<option value=" .$ri['Proses'] . ">" . $ri['Proses'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select> ";

        mysql_close($cn);
        ?>      

    </center></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style ="margin-left:350px"/>
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: give a value for every option and attach a onchange event,on change take the value of selected value and send it to server via ajax query your database and send the response as json,on complete of ajax fill the depended drop down with new values .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use Jquery to make the ajax request, it's more easy. To know how the proccess should be, you can read the examples in posts below:

http://www.snilesh.com/resources/jquery/jquery-dynamic-selectbox/

http://www.codingcereal.com/2009/09/autopopulate-select-dropdown-box-using-jquery/

I hope that guides can help you.